# Is a subclass always in the same package as a superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

So there are two classes defined to be:

```
    public class SuperClass {
        int count = 5;
        SuperClass() {
        }

    }

    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
        SubClass() {
            super();

    }

SubClass sub = new Subclass();
System.out.println(sub.count); // prints out 5
```

Unless my understanding of the default visibility modifier is wrong, I thought that the default modifier is that only classes in the same packages can access the variable count. So this implies that my SubClass is in the same package as my SuperClass but I haven't specified that they are in the same package anywhere in my code. Does this mean that a SubClass is ALWAYS in the same package as the SuperClass?

Comment: Did you define your two classes in two different files? If so, in which package did you put them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right: default access modifier (also called [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)) is not accessible from a subclass if it's in another package. In your case - both classes are in the same directory which implicitly means that they are in the same package.

Comment: Except his question had more a general scope + look at the classes, they are public in his case so the question was more general.

Comment: @YassinHH the visibility of the class is out of this context. The only concern of this question is the visibility of the variable `count`.

Comment: He choose the exemple of the variable to bring up the general question. But whatever... Still a downvote i guess..

Comment: @YassinHH you missed the point, if you want to catch up read about access-modifiers (there's a link to it in the answer above) and then read his question again.

Answer (score 2):

No, a subclass can be in a different package than its super class.

It's hard to say just from your code snippet, but I'm assuming that all of your sample code is in one file? If that's the case, then both classes *will* be in the same package. And if you haven't specified a `package` at the top of the file, then it's the "default package" that they both belong to.

If you were to separate those two classes into different files and place them in different packages, you'd find what you expect: `SubClass` will no longer be able to access the field defined in `SuperClass`.

Comment: See my comment to YassinHH.

Comment: I don't follow. I said he _can't_ access the field in the `SuperClass` from the `SubClass` if they are in different packages. Why the down vote?

Comment: I retracted the downvote, but note that your answer is not clear since you start with "No, they can be in different packages." which is not true if he wants to be able to access that variable.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the first sentence to clarify. I was answering the question: `Is a subclass always in the same package as a superclass in Java?`